How to customize injected link tag for Vite CSS side effect import?
I have a Remix app where I am importing CSS like this import "./app.css" to inject a link element in the head element. Is there a way I can add attributes to the injected tag? I would like to add a media attribute.
For example, the generated link element is like: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/root-BCmdghdI.css">. I want it to be <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/root-BCmdghdI.css" media="screen">. How can I achieve this? Is there a config option for it?
